# How to install Dashlane on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I use the password manager Dashlane on Windows. However, I cannot use the same on Ubuntu. I tried installing it using Wine but it didn't help. Can anybody suggest alternative methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now installed [Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine/) and Dashlane works like a charm!

Comment: I went to install this and I got a warning about being unable to update in the future if I did this. Doesn't work though. How should I run it?

Comment: Isn't `Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)` the same as `Wine`?

Comment: It is actually the fancy name for wine

Answer (score 2):

My best solution so far is to host a small Windows 10 VM in VirtualBox which runs Dashlane and Chrome.  I enter that environment when I need web credentials.

I love Dashlane in all of my non-ubuntu devices, but I've had flaky results at best running Dashlane in Ubuntu using Wine.  I've had to reinstall it a few times already just to keep it functional.  As such I recommend virtualization or remoting into a windows machine when you need to access to Dashlane from ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Install [playonlinux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux) [image: Install playonlinux]:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then install and run Dashlane with Wine:

- Download Dashlane App -- save the file to Desktop or other location.
- Right-click on Dashlane installation file.
- Open with "Wine Windows Program Loader."

Comment: did you get those browser extension working?

Comment: Doesn't work. The app keeps complaining about not having an internet connection. It then exits. 

fixme:wininet:query_global_option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE: semi-stub
fixme:wininet:query_global_option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE: semi-stub
fixme:wininet:query_global_option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE: semi-stub
fixme:wininet:query_global_option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE: semi-stub
fixme:wininet:query_global_option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE: semi-stub